# Change debug level wso2 emm jaggery application

Tags: logging, wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-iot

I'm modifying the emm jaggery application of the WSO2 EMM server, and i'm trying to see
 the debug messages, I've modified the "logLevel": "debug" propierty in the jaggery.conf file 
, restarted the server but i still cannot see anything in the wso2carbon.log file.

How i can see these messages ?

I'm directly modifying the source code at /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm

I'll really appreciate your help

Gabriel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue i followed these steps :

1. cd
   /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm
2. edit the jaggery.conf file
3. modify the "logLevel": "info" entry to "logLevel": "debug"
4. restart the server and enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

Step1.  Locate  log4j.properties file which can be found at /repository/conf directory.

Step2. Enable debug logs for all WSO2 related components by configuring following parameter in to debug.

By default,  you can find this

```
         log4j.logger.org.wso2=INFO
```

To enable debug logs,  You can change it as following

```
         log4j.logger.org.wso2=DEBUG
```

Step3.  Restart the server.